# Using sed selectively

Tags: sed, awk, grep

My dump file looks something like this...

```
--
-- Current Database: `Batch`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `Batch` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin */;

USE `Batch`;

--
-- Table structure for table `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` (
  `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `VERSION` bigint(20) default NULL,
```

I want to change the DB name found in the create table and "use" statement to pd_Batch.

```
sed 's/Batch/pd_Batch/' test.sql
```

The above statement will do the needful. But I do not want any "Batch" word to be changed. It should change only the word found on the line
starting with CREATE DATABASE or USE.

**Update:**

The by-product of this question is there is more than one DB in the test.sql file. So the following words needs to be prefixed with pd_

```
Batch
cash
country
rules
currency
state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/CREATE DATABASE\|USE/s/Batch/pd_Batch/' test.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change multiple DB names in a single sed?

Comment: @shan: yes, something like `sed '/CREATE DATABASE\|USE/{s/Batch/pd_Batch/;s/Foo/pd_Foo/;s/Bar/pd_Bar/}'`